# Issue with connect Spring security LDAP

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, ldap

How can I realize LDAP authorization in Spring boot application if  authentication is performed on server using DBMS_LDAP.

Server returning **null** if user wasn't authorized else returning **user properties**.

dependencies:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
compile("org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core")
compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap")
compile("org.springframework:spring-tx")
compile("com.unboundid:unboundid-ldapsdk")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
compile("org.apache.directory.server:apacheds-server-jndi:1.5.5")
```

AuthenticationManagerBuilder config:

```
 auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
            .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=Users")
            .userSearchBase("ou=gk")
            .userSearchFilter("(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))")
            .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
            .groupSearchFilter("(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))")
            .contextSource(contextSource());
```

contextSource:

```
@Bean(name = "contextSource")
public LdapContextSource  contextSource() {

    LdapContextSource cs = new LdapContextSource ();
    cs.setUrl( "ldaps://server.corp.company.ru:666/");
    cs.setBase("dc=corp,dc=company,dc=ru");
    cs.setUserDn("cn=username,dc=corp,dc=company,dc=ru");
    cs.setPassword("password");
    cs.afterPropertiesSet();
    return cs;
}
```

Throwing error:

> Reason: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090400, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1]; nested exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090400, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1]

Comment: The error often indicates that something is wrong with your credentials. Are you sure that you're using the correct DN to connect with the LDAP/AD instance?

Comment: yes, it's correct. We uses unboundid ldap sdk in java ee application and here uses same DN and all works correclty.

Comment: If you work with passwords in Active Directory, you *have* to connect over SSL (port 636). Are you?